# afnetworking in singletone and waiting requests from another controller (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am writing an Apple iPhone application.
A have got a class - singleton which sending a requests to the server (ServerManager) and a ViewController which using methods of singletone and another methods (analyzing requests for example).
How to perform queries from singletone in viewcontroller on the line? One after the other? Not parallel?

```
    //for example authoriztion in Twitter
    //here my query for the Twitter Server

    - (void) getTweetsFromTW:(NSInteger) count
                   onSuccess:(void(^)(NSArray* news)) success
                   onFailure:(void(^)(NSError* error, NSInteger statusCode)) failure {
        //NSString* countStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", count];
        NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ld", count], @"count", nil];
        NSError* requestError = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSURLRequest* myRequest = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                                   URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                   URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"
                                   parameters:params
                                   error:&requestError];
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
         sendTwitterRequest:myRequest
         completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
             if (data) {
                 NSError* jsonError;
                 NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
                 //NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray); //вывод ответа сервера
                 NSMutableArray* textsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                 for (int i = 0; i < [jsonArray count]; i++) {
                     NSArray* test = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i], nil];
                     NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:test
                                                                      forKeys:[test valueForKey:@"intField"]];
                     NSDictionary* dictionary = dict[[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
                     //NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"text"]);  //вывод текстов твитов
                     [textsArray addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"text"]];
                 }
                 if (success) {
                     success(textsArray);
                 }
                 
                 
             }
         }];
        
    }







//here is my viewcontroller
        [[ServerManager sharedManager] getTweetsFromTW:10
                                             onSuccess:^(NSArray *news) {
                                                 for (int i = 0; i < [news count]; i++) {
                                                     NSLog(@"%@", [news objectAtIndex:i]);
                                                 }
                                                 [_textsFromTW addObjectsFromArray:news];
                                             }
                                             onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
             
                                             }];
        
        //I need send this requests in a line not parallel
        
        [[ServerManager sharedManager] getNewsFromVK:300
                                              filter:@"post"
                                           onSuccess:^(NSArray *news) {
                                               for (int i = 0; i < [news count]; i++) {
                                                   NSLog(@"%@", [[news objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"]);
                                                   if ([[news objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"] != nil) {
                                                       [_textsFromVK addObject:[[news objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"]];
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                           onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
             
                                           }];
```

Comment: "How to perform queries from singletone in viewcontroller on the line? One after the other? Not parallel?" - What kind of query do you want to run from a Singleton class?

Comment: I found an answer some years ago)
PromiseKit can help

Comment: That's nice. I guess I have more insight into things with Swift, GCD and NetworkQueue in general now and that can also help you achieve what you wanted to do.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine

Comment: @RahulSharma cool. Thanks for this link)